# Accessing Model attributes in Thymleaf and Spring boot on on-click attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to show an alert confirmation before delete action to ask the user if he want to delete "name of employee" and i want to use the model attribute to get the name.

> 

this is the code that im using

```
<a onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete @{emplyeename}')" th:href="@{/admin/emp/delete/{id}(id=${empVo.id})}">
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```